# Pyplot connect to timer event?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The same way I now have `plt.connect('button_press_event', self.on_click)`
I would like to have something like `plt.connect('each_five_seconds_event', self.on_timer)`

How can I achieve this in a way that's most similar to what I've shown above?

EDIT:
I tried

```
fig = plt.subplot2grid((num_cols, num_rows), (col, row), rowspan=rowspan,
                           colspan=colspan)
timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=100, callbacks=[(self.on_click)])
timer.start()
```

And got

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'canvas'
```

Also, is this

```
 new_timer(interval=100, callbacks=[(self.on_click)])
```

good, or do I have to pass more stuff in there, as in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib has a backend-agnostic timer that integrates with the gui's event loop. Have a look at `figure.canvas.new_timer(...)`.

The call signature is a touch akward, but it works. (You need to explicitly specify empty sequences and dicts if your call back function(s) don't take arguments or kwargs.)

As a minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def on_timer():
    print 'Hi!'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# The interval is in milliseconds.  
# "callbacks" expects a sequence of (func, args, kwargs)
timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=5000, callbacks=[(on_timer, [], {})])
timer.start()

plt.show()
```

And as a "fancier" example that animates a 2D brownian walk:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def on_timer(line, x, y):
    x.append(x[-1] + np.random.normal(0, 1))
    y.append(y[-1] + np.random.normal(0, 1))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    line.axes.relim()
    line.axes.autoscale_view()
    line.axes.figure.canvas.draw()

x, y = [np.random.normal(0, 1)], [np.random.normal(0, 1)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, y, color='aqua', marker='o')

timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=100, 
                             callbacks=[(on_timer, [line, x, y], {})])
timer.start()

plt.show()
```

Comment: How does this integrate with what I already have(plt.connect() stuff)?
Can I use both of them, do they play well together?

Comment: They should integrate just fine.  They're both controlled by the same event loop. You can use both of them together.

Comment: So, here timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=100, 
                             callbacks=[(on_timer, [line, x, y], {})])
can I pass my old on_click method instead?

Comment: And, after the timer, Ctrl+C does not work, why is this?